# Clustering across multiple modes of an array as an extension of biclustering?

Tags: clustering

[Biclustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering) encompasses techniques for clustering a (usually) data matrix among its rows **and** columns. Some forms of data are multidimensional arrays rather than 2D arrays, and it would be beneficial to cluster across multiple modes (that is "axes") of a data array.

Is there a literature on generalizations of biclustering to k-mode arrays (i.e. sometimes called "tensors", although I don't require it in the multilinear map sense of the term)?